# how to rectify this error in decision tree model AttributeError: module 'sklearn.tree' has no attribute 'predict'

Tags: pandas, decision-tree

i am not able to correct above error in jupiter
AttributeError: module 'sklearn.tree' has no attribute 'predict'

to run decision tree

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

`sklearn.tree` is a module that contains 2 main models:

- one for regression [`DecisionTreeRegressor`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeRegressor.html)
- one for classification [`DecisionTreeClassifier`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html).

You must create an instance of one of these models.

For example:

```
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier

clf = DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)  # <- fit first
y_pred = clf.predict(X_test)  # <- then predict
```